# Chrome extension create.window: How to use the height parameter?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, window, height

I'm trying to use chrome.create.window to get a popup window and something goes wrong.

Here's my background.js code:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
if (request.type === 'open_window') {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL('win.html'),
            active: false
        }, function(tab) {
            chrome.windows.create({
                tabId: tab.id,
                type: 'popup',
                height: '200',

                focused: true
            });
        });
}
});
```

Before I've added `height: '200',` I got what I wanted: a window jumped out of the browser. When I add this line, the window opens as another tab of the opened window. Why is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a number instead of a string:`200` → `"200"`. You would know that if you [opened the console for the background page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029):

> Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'height': Expected 'integer' but got 'string'.

I suggest to use the `url` option with [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create), because it's slightly more efficient:

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL('win.html'),
    type: 'popup',
    height: 200,
    focused: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I've opened the console and didn't see any error. I must have missed something. I'll check into it. +1 for the tip.